# Run perl online

Tags: perl, apache

I want to run a Perl script online, but I don't know how.
In PHP you need to start with `<?php`, so do you have to start with something like that in Perl?
And does Apache automatically recognize Perl? Or do I have to upload Perl and let it point to it using  `#!/path/to/perl`?
Can I use `print()` to display HTML?

Comment: I found on tizag.com that you have to use the #!pathtoPERL.

Comment: You don't *have* to use a shebang, that's just one method.

Comment: Tizag is quite possibly the worst Perl tutorial in the world, see [review](http://perl-tutorial.org/#index6h1).

Comment: @daxim — That explains why W3Schools don't have a Perl tutorial; they couldn't write one worse than tizag's!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In PHP you need to start with `<?php`, so do you have to start with something like that in Perl?

There are frameworks (such as Mason) which work like that, but it is more typical to have a standard Perl program which outputs the page.

> And does Apache automatically recognize Perl?

Apache doesn't automatically recognise any kind of server side programming.

> Or do I have to upload Perl and let it point to it using #!/path/to/perl?

You would need to have Perl installed on the server. You would generally start a script that way (but not necessarily, e.g. if you were using mod_perl), but would have to configure the server to recognise it as an executable and run it (just as you have to configure the server to recognise files ending with `.php` as scripts to run with PHP).

> Can I use print() to display HTML?

Yes.

You should probably start by looking at the question [Web Programming For The Non-Web Programmer (in Perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141042/web-programming-for-the-non-web-programmer-in-perl).

Comment: So what do I have to do? Upload PERL to my server and let the '#!' statement point to it?

Comment: If your server doesn't have Perl (there is no such thing as PERL) installed, then you need to install it. Just "uploading it" is a very bad idea as you'll probably get broken links to shared libraries. The section of the accepted answer (for the question I linked to) marked "How to get a webserver to talk to your Perl" has some pointers for getting started.

Comment: How can I run a cmd-line command on my server? I only have a directory on the server...

Comment: Do I have o contact the serverowner?

Comment: @11684 — If you don't have command line access, and Perl isn't installed already, then you will need to consult with someone who does to get the software you want to run installed.

Answer (score 1):

Must you use Apache? If not here is an alternative to consider.

I have found that the built-in servers and templating engine in the [Mojolicious framework](http://mojolicio.us)  work very naturally for inline Perl within HTML. The tags are of the form `<%==` but work the same way. Also it has good documentation and examples to get you going.

Edit: It seems that there are ways to use Apache with Mojolicious too, see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious::Guides::Cookbook, though the built-in servers have worked well for me, with FAR less (ie no) configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTP doesn't automatically understand Perl or PHP for that matter. For PHP to work, you have to have the Apache httpd module called something like `mod_php.so` or `libphp5.so` installed. However, since many websites use PHP in this manner, this Apache httpd module is normally installed.

Just as you need *mod_php* in order to use PHP in Apache's httpd web server, you need to do is make sure your web server is using [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) if you want to use Perl in a similar manner.

You'll need to build and install `mod_perl` which can be tricky -- especially if you don't control the machine the server is on.

The other way to use Perl is to use what's known as [CGI-Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html). This is much easier to setup, but it is also much more *dangerous* since it can lead to someone being able to run unauthorized programs on your Apache httpd server.

In this case, you need to set up a *CGI-BIN* directory, and configure [Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/cgi.html). This is fairly simple. Once you do that, you put all of your Perl scripts into the _CGI_BIN_ directory. In this case, your Perl scripts will have to handle all of the communication between your web server and the web client and handle all displays. Fortunately, it's not too difficult in perl since Perl gives you the basic modules to do this.

Comment: *The* other way? There are lots of other ways, mod_psgi and FastCGI spring to mind.

Comment: @Quentin - You're right that there are lots of other ways. However, the poster asked about Perl like PHP support in Apache httpd, and mod_perl would be the closest. The big problem is you have to normally rebuild Apache to get it. It's the only way I've gotten it to work. _The other way_ mainly referred to a way to get Perl in without rebuilding httpd. CGI is built in, and only has to be configured which is pretty simple. FastCGI and PSGI are interesting, but like mod_perl, you have to recompile httpd. Not familiar with mod_psgi, but it sounds interesting.